# Github pages lose images

Tags: image, github

I'm working on a project currently that I had to completely reinitialize.  I'm trying to push to gitub, and it works...but for some reason all of the images are broken accept for one.  Anyone have any idea why this would be happening?  Here is the url to see what is happening:

http://ryan8765.github.io/jessica/index.html

Answer (score 1):

Believe I figured this out.  When pushing a project to github the project becomes case sensitive and any links in your project that aren't case sensitive will be broke.  Case sensitive isn't an issue with links locally (at least for me), but when it gets to github it is.

Comment: I guess you are working on a Windows. Windows handles file names (kind of) case insensitive. GitHub pages probably runs on Linux which handles file names case sensitive.

Comment: It's not just GitHub::Pages, but almost anything non-Windows that is case-sensitive.